# GWT Double or Long

Tags: gwt

Is the use of Double (boxed type) highly recommended over the use of Long (boxed type) in GWT. I've read many official resources (I think all of them) but I couldn't realize how harmful is to use Long objects instead of Double ones. I'm heavily concerned about performance but if the cost does not make big difference, I would stay with Longs.

Comment: Unless you are building a game with 20 objects flying around at 60fps, you should not worry about a difference between Long and Double.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, both, long and Long are implemented in GWT as an Array of two numbers (containing the low and high half of the long). The reason is that the integer precision of Javascript numbers is limited to 53 bit, but a Long contains 64 bit. All mathematical operations are turned into complex multi-number array operations, which is quite expensive.

That said, it really depends on what you do with the Longs: If you just use them as IDs or similar, and long operations are not one of the main bottlenecks of your program, it may just be fine to stick to Longs.

Comment: If I often receive thousands and thousands of JSON arrays with many numbers (greater than int) and need to display them in various ways (say charts and tables). Like dealing with live data. How should I reason about that?

Comment: I'd use a GWT JSON library that provides access to the data without needing any conversion. For pure client side code, JavaScriptObject / JsArrayXxx may just work fine

Comment: If the JSON data uses numbers greater than int, then if it is actually compatible with JS, it is less than long, and will fit in a double. JSON doesn't specify number precision, but if your JSON data is meant to be used with JavaScript (which is limited as @StefanHaustein suggests), then it must be representable by a Java double.